# Nuxt link with dynamic `to` prop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

I am trying to automatically add UTM tracking parameters to all nuxt links, so I made a component for this (let me know if there's a better way!).

```html
<template>
  <nuxt-link :to="url" :target="$attrs.target"><slot></slot></nuxt-link>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'ArticleLink',
  props: {
    to: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    date: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    url(): string {
      const url = this.to.startsWith('/')
        ? `${process.env.VUE_APP_ORIGIN}${this.to}`
        : this.to;
      const urlObject = new URL(url);
      urlObject.searchParams.append('utm_source', 'article');
      urlObject.searchParams.append('date', this.date);
      console.log(this.to, urlObject.href);
      return urlObject.href;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

The problem is when I use it on relative links, the `to` property for some reason combines the initial href, with the calculated one:

```html
<article-link date="20221109" to="/">link</article-link>
```

this is rendered as:

```html
http://localhost:3000/current/path/http://localhost:3000/?utm_source=article&date-20221109`
```

What's strange is the `console.log` shows the correct conversion from `/` to `http://localhost:3000/?utm_source=article&date=20221109`

Also strange is if I use Vue devtools to inspect the `<NuxtLink>` it shows a correct `to` prop.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I'm using vue router links incorrectly (see: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1131)

When I pass an absolute URL to the `:to` prop, it adds it to the end of the current URL. So I have to return `urlObject.pathname + urlObject.search` instead of returning `urlObject.href`

:shrug: